# How to get list data using ListData.SVC in Silverlight Application?

Tags: wcf, listdata.svc

I am “not” looking for solution which uses webrequest to get xml from listdata.svc.
I am "not” looking for clientcontext ( since Silverlight app will be deployed to the different server where sharepoint is not installed).

Any code will be helpful.

Comment: You can use the ClientContext within a deployed application, outside of a SharePoint environment.  In fact, both would be good solutions for Silverlight application.  What are your real constraints to avoid those ?

Comment: You're not looking to get XML from ListData.svc? Do you realise it doesn't really spit out much else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointandsilverlighttrainingcourse_accessingsharepointlistdatausinglistdatalab

Very fresh Virtual Lab

Comment: That's exactly what i was looking for.